# When does a pseudo-Cauchy sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences

> Suppose $(x_n), (y_n)$ are increasing and positive sequences such that $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and $$x_{n+1}-x_n<y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Then is $(x_n)$ also a Cauchy sequence?

I know that $x_{n+1}-x_n\to 0$ does not imply that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy but does the extra condition given above help? I tried to write

\begin{align}
x_m-x_n &=x_{m}-x_{m-1}+x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}+\ldots+ x_{n+1}-x_n \\\\
&< y_m-y_{m-2}+y_{m-1}-y_{m-3}+\ldots+y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}  
\end{align}

but couldn't proceed.

Comment: Note that $$ x_m - x_n \leq y_{m} + y_{m-1} - y_{n} - y_{n-1} $$ holds for any $m > n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to express $y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}$ as the sum of differences of adjacent sequence elements:
$$
x_{n+1}-x_n<y_{n+1}-y_{n-1} = (y_{n+1}-y_n) + (y_n-y_{n-1})
$$
and therefore
$$ 
0 \le x_{n+p}-x_n = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(x_{k+1}-x_n) 
< \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(y_{k+1}-y_n) + \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(y_n-y_{k-1}) \\
= (y_{n+p}-y_n) + (y_{n+p-1}-y_{n-1})
$$
for all $n, p \ge 1$. Use this to show that if $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence then $(x_n)$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

Note that the condition that $(y_n)$ is increasing it not needed for the proof.